# Copy and paste from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 20

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10, oracle, copy, paste

I am running Ubuntu 20 through Oracle VM and I'd like to be able to copy and paste lengthy strings into Terminal from my Windows OS.

I have installed Guest Additions and turned on Bidirectional under advanced settings but I am still unable to do this. Quite frustrating.

Anyone having a similar issue or with a solution?

Comment: Are you able to copy and paste between the Virtual Box and Windows at all?